Active Directory GPO not applying computer configuration
I seem to be getting stuck with Computer Policies not being applied by machines in our domain.
The User specific settings are being applied (desktop background etc.), but I can't see anything in the Computer Configuration with a GPResult on the client.
I have read about this Loopback policy and have tried to enable it, but it is a Computer Configuration so it isn't showing up on the client.
One of the changes I'm trying to make is to enable Remote Desktop, but like the Loopback policy, this appears to be a Computer Configuration.
Perhaps these photos will shed some more light.
Active Directory Perspective

Client Perspective


Update (1)
Security settings on the policy


What is the security permissions on the GPO? It needs to have Read and Apply for Authenticated Users, Domain Computers, or a security group.

@GregAskew Yep it has those permissions, I've updated the question with a screengrab.

How could there be zero settings and zero policies?

I'm not sure to be honest. You can see the Branding Policy User Configuration bits are being taken by the client, but even in that GPO it has some Computer Configuration which seems to be stripped. I'm not sure what logs or info I can provide to paint a better picture, but happy to provide as requested.

You should check the version stored in the ini file in sysvol. Also enable group policy environment debug logging. It will show more detail. That is obviously not close to a normal environment, I wouldn't be surprised if sysvol is jacked up or not replicating.

Any hints in the local event log?

@GregAskew Ok so looking at the GPT.INI file in one of the Policies it says Version=4390949 It also says on all the GPT.INI files in all policy folders displayName=New Group Policy Object Also enabling debugging on the client shows a huge log as expected. I can see an ldap_bind_s failed with 82 error however I'm not sure if that's a false positive as I would have though LDAP issues would prevent the User configuration changes as well as the Computer configuration changes.

@M.Behrens The only thing I can gather is an Error 1030 in the local event log when trying a gpupdate - which also says A directory service error has occurred in the details tab.

Ok I've found my issue(s).
It was related to the LDAP SRV records on the DNS server running on the DC.
There simply was no _ldap._tcp.DOMAIN.com record.
DCDiag /test:DNS is what I was running on the DC to troubleshoot this.
We enabled Active Directory retrospectively after this machine was already running a DNS server. So I wonder if that meant the auto creation of the DNS entries wasn't done completely.
I can see it made the dc._msdcs.DOMAIN.com zone along with entries in the zone, however it hasn't touched the existing zone which is DOMAIN.com.

"We enabled Active Directory retrospectively after this machine was already running a DNS server. So I wonder if that meant the auto creation of the DNS entries wasn't done completely."
Is the domain DNS zone Active-Directory integrated? Does it allow dynamic updates? Does the server use itself as its DNS server in its NIC configuration?

Also, you really should have more than one Domain Controller. REALLY.

@Massimo Yes the DC is using 127.0.0.1 as it's DNS server - on the DNS server we've been using forwarders for zones outside our scope. I did change the zone to Active-Directory Integrated and allowed dynamic updates via Secure only for the time being. Also totally agree with the more than one DC, this is purely a proof of concept as we move to a directory based setup with our machines.

Try restarting the NETLOGON service; this forces a DC to re-register all its SRV records in the domain DNS.

@Massimo Aha! Restarting netlogon has indeed created a load of extra DNS entries!

With a single DC, you run into a race condition on server startup where AD needs DNS, but DNS needs AD; this increases the server boot time a lot and can cause errors such as DNS SRV records not being properly registered.
